# Form with uploading a video to API in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I've been working on my project that seems have trouble, in my project there is form with form that could upload files (1 video and 1 image) to backend, the image is fine because i was encoding it, the problem is on the video. i've had tried many approach but there is nothing changed. here is my code:

```
angular                                                                                            
.module('Webconsole_Recharge',['angularFileUpload','base64','naif.base64'])                        
.controller('terminalAssetCtrl',function ($scope,FileUploader,cfpLoadingBar,$base64,callApi,$timeou
    cfpLoadingBar.complete();                                                                      


    $scope.uploader = new FileUploader();                                                          



    var uploadURL = "/fileUpload";                                                                 

    $scope.uploader1 = new FileUploader();                                                         
    // var encodeTemp,encodeTemp1;                                                                 
    $scope.encodeTemp1="";                                                                         
    $scope.getTerminalId = function () {                                                           
        callApi.callGetApi('terminal/list').then(function (response) {                             
            // if(response.STATUS == "failed"){                                                    
            //     console.log(error);                                                             
            // }else {                                                                             
            //     $scope.getID = response.data.TERMINAL;                                          
            //     console.log($scope.getID);                                                      
            // }                                                                                   
            $scope.getID = response.data.TERMINAL;                                                 
            console.log($scope.getID);                                                             
           $scope.getTerminalByID = response.data.TERMINAL[3].TERMINAL_ID;                         
            console.log($scope.getTerminalByID);                                                   
        })                                                                                         
    };                                                                                             
    $scope.getTerminalId();                                                                        



    $scope.uploadFile= function (callback,e) {                                                     
        var file= $scope.uploader;                                                                 
        $scope.video = document.getElementById('fileVideo').files[0];                              
        var myFile = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify($scope.video));                               
        console.log(myFile);                                                                       
        // console.log($scope.video);                                                              
        // console.log(fd.getAll('fileVideo'));                                                    
        var fd = new FormData();                                                                   
        fd.append('TOP_ASSET',$scope.video);                                                       
        var file2 = $scope.uploader1;                                                              
        var base64;                                                                                
        if(file.queue[0]._file.size>=209715200){                                                   
            console.log("File terlalu besar");                                                     
        }                                                                                          
        else {                                                                                     
            $scope.encodeTemp1='';                                                                 
            $scope.encodeTemp="" ;                                                                 
            var tempDataPromise = '';                                                              
            angular.forEach(file2.queue,function (value,e) {                                       
                $scope.reader1 = new FileReader();                                                 
                $scope.reader1.readAsDataURL(value._file)                                          
                $scope.reader1.onload = function (ev) {                                            
                    base64 = ev.target.result.substring(ev.target.result.indexOf(',') + 1,ev.target
                    $scope.encodeTemp1 += base64+' ';                                              
                    // $scope.saveTemp($scope.encodeTemp1);                                        
                    // $scope.temp.push($scope.encodeTemp1);                                       
                    // console.log($scope.encodeTemp1)                                             
                    // console.log($scope.encodeTemp1);                                            
                    $scope.encodeTemp += $scope.encodeTemp1 + ' ';                                 

                    console.log($scope.encodeTemp);                                                
                    // var encodeTemp = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('encodeTemp1'));     
                    // if(encodeTemp){                                                             
                    //     $scope.encodeTemp = [];                                                 
                    //     for(var i=0;i<encodeTemp.length;i++){                                   
                    //         $scope.encodeTemp.push(encodeTemp[i]);                              
                    //     }                                                                       
                    //     console.log($scope.encodeTemp);                                         
                    // }                                                                           
                }                                                                                  
            });                                                                                    


            $timeout(function(){                                                                   
                var request = {                                                                    
                    'TERMINAL_ID' : $scope.getTerminalByID,                                        
                    'TOP_ASSET' : myFile,                                                          
                    'BOTTOM_ASSET' : $scope.encodeTemp,                                            
                    'DESCRIPTION' : $scope.description                                             
                }                                                                                  
                 // var fd = new FormData();                                                       
                 // fd.set('TERMINAL_ID',$scope.getTerminalByID);                                  
                 // fd.set('DESCRIPTION',$scope.description);                                      
                 // fd.set('BOTTOM_ASSET',$scope.encodeTemp);                                      
                 // fd.set('TOP_ASSET',file.queue[0]);                                             

                callApi.callPostApi('uploadUpdateTerminalAsset',request).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.STATUS == "failed"){                                              
                        console.log(error);                                                        
                    }else {                                                                        
                        // $state.go('restricted.dashboard');                                      
                    }                                                                              
                })                                                                                 
            },3000)                                                                                
        }                                                                                          
    }                                                                                              

});
```

in inspect elements, on the network side "TOP_ASSET : {}".
anyone here have considered which part that i'm wrong? (sorry for the mess code,i'll fix that)

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.

Comment: **Restart from scratch.** Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem.